# How to read a file from S3 with KMS encryption using Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-kms

I am trying to read a file from S3 using the spark.read.csv. But, I am unable to read that for a file with KMS encryption. I have the KMS key available. How to specify them in the spark session while configuring it.

Answer (score 0):

For SSE-KMS it is automatic: when a file is encrypted the key ID is stored along with the object, to decrypt the file S3-side it talks straight to KMS to decrypt (if you can read the key)

for client side, AWS EMR does support this. The open source S3A connector *doesn't*, because for many years S3 client side encryption always padded the data so things would break. That's changed now, but nobody has (Jan 2021) supplied the patch